# .Net Runtime Library for Delphi Programming

Tags: c#, .net, delphi

I use .Net Runtime Library for Delphi and load assembly (C#) in my project with success. I have problem only when try to get string result from assembly.
My C# code is:

```
[DispId(0)]
public int Add(int a, int b)
{
  return a + b;
}
[DispId(1)]
public string GetProtectedID(string InString)
{
  return "12345";
}
```

My Delphi code is:

```
_SISign = dispinterface
['{AAFE8566-37E1-485B-9727-7223F7731F19}']
  function Add(a, b : Integer) : Integer; dispid 0;
  function GetProtectedID(InString: String): String; dispid 1;
  end;

var
  oSISign : _SISign;
begin
  WriteLn(oSISign.Add(10, 20));
  WriteLn(oSISign.GetProtectedID('SomeText'));
end;
```

first line return 30, second nothing.

Comment: Are you sure the correct version of the assembly is loaded?

Comment: Delphi string and C# string types are not compatible. If you are going to write a COM compatible DLL (which can be consumed in Delphi, VB, ...) you need to use COM string types like BSTR.

Comment: You'll want to use `WideString` on the Delphi side. But it might be simpler just to use Robert Giesecke's UnmanagedExports.

Comment: Question 4,294,967,295 asking *Why doesn't using Delphi string for interop work?*. Why can't people do basic searches here first for questions about *Delphi C# string* and find one of those previous posts?

Answer (score -2):

I found some solution for now.

In C#, I change:

```
public integer GetProtectedID(string InString, out string OutString)
{
  OutString = "Result HERE";
  return 0;
}
```

In Delphi Programming, I changed to:

```
_SIXmlSign = dispinterface
    ['{4a674fd3-244f-4802-9b1d-9eb0b0efb282}']
  function GetProtectedID(InString: String; var OutString: String): Integer; dispid 1;
end;
```

and now code working

Comment: The Delphi function prototype looks wrong. Can you check? If the comma is actually a semicolon then you are declaring OutString as a variant type, and you are *not* testing InString in any event.

Comment: Yes @Dsm. Now is changed.

Comment: Sorry, but this is still not correct. It does not compile. There cannot be a comma where you have it.

Comment: That's not right. You can't use delphi native string for interop.